# Simple dynamic TSQL query syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

This may be an easy answer but I've been staring at it for too long...

I have the following query that takes a stored procedure input parameter as a variable name and counts the records in that table.  I'd like to retrieve the results of the dynamic statement (@toStartStr) into a variable (@toStart).

```
-- @tempTableName = SProc input parameter
DECLARE @toStartStr nvarchar(150);
DECLARE @toStart int;
SET @toStartStr = 'SELECT @toStart = COUNT(ID) FROM ' + @tempTableName;
EXEC(@toStartStr);
```

Right now, an error suggests that @toStart cannot be concatenated with the string SELECT, but this is the gist of what I want.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Or suggest an alternative?  FYI SQL 2008 R2.   Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255);

DECLARE @toStart INT;

SET @sql = N'SELECT @toStart = COUNT(ID) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tempTableName);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@toStart INT OUTPUT', @toStart OUTPUT;

PRINT @toStart;
```

However there is a much easier and more efficient way to do this, if you're okay with ignoring current in-flight transactions (and you're using SQL Server 2005 or better - please specify the version when asking questions!).

```
DECLARE @toStart INT;

SELECT @toStart = SUM(rows) 
  FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tempTableName)
  AND index_id IN (0,1);

PRINT @toStart;
```

Just for completeness, here is a solution for SQL Server 2000, which also doesn't require any special privileges (just connect and member of public):

```
DECLARE @toStart INT;

SELECT @toStart = [rows] 
  FROM sysindexes
  WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@tempTableName)
  AND indid IN (0,1);

PRINT @toStart;
```

That said, if you're using a count to determine what the next ID might be, or something like that, I think you're approaching this the wrong way, since rows can be deleted and if it's an identity column values can be skipped due to rollbacks.

Comment: It's not always true that you are a **sa** user. I think admin rights are required to execute this query. Right?

Comment: Nope, I just tested on a system where I do not have admin rights and it runs fine.

Comment: @Kanavi No, admin rights are not required to view sys.partitions. Did you try it before telling me to remove the code?

Comment: SQL 2008 R2.  And a record count is fine, as this is a static temporary table from a file import.

Comment: Your SQL 2005+ solution worked perfectly.  I'll update the question to make it more specific.