# SQL - inserting into a table defined by a nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have several tables in my database of the format PREFIX_FeatureName. For example:

- `Processed_CallingCountry` (featureName nvarchar(max) null, escalatedCount int null, featureValue nvarchar(max) null, RequestNumber int null)
- `Processed_CallingCity` (featureName nvarchar(max) null, escalatedCount int null, featureValue nvarchar(max) null, RequestNumber int null)

  [...]

Currently, I have one stored procedure per table, that computes the feature, and inserts it into the proper table. The processing code for every feature is almost identical, with the feature name being different.

Example:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(IsSpecial) 
     FROM [dbo].[FeaturesBase] 
     WHERE CreatedTime < a.CreatedTime 
       AND CallingCountry = a.CallingCountry ) AS EscalatedCount,
    'CallingCountry' AS FeatureName,
    RequestNumber,
    CallingCountry AS FeatureValue
FROM 
    [dbo].[CssFeaturesBase] a
```

This code is copy-pasted for all features, changing only the feature name - in the previous example, 'CallingCountry' will be replaced with other strings, one per stored procedure.

Is there a way of creating a single stored procedure that will take a string as input, and do the computations using the string/`nvarchar` as the parameter?

Basically, how do I do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE process (@featureName nvarchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO ('Processed' + @featureName)  -- use the table defined by the string
        (SELECT SUM(IsSpecial) 
         FROM [dbo].[FeaturesBase] 
         WHERE CaseCreatedTime < a.CaseCreatedTime 
           AND @featureName = a.@featureName) AS EscalatedCount,  --use @featureName as column name
        @featureName AS FeatureName,   --use the string literal here
        RequestNumber,
        @featureName AS FeatureValue  --select the proper value
    FROM
        [dbo].[FeaturesBase] a
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL.  Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11108520/3854195

Comment: Is the FeatureName the same for all rows in the table? the FeatureName part of the table name the same value that gets inserted into the FeatureName field in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use dynamic sql to get around this :

Something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE process (@featureName nvarchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = 'SELECT INTO (Processed_'+ @featureName + ') 
        (SELECT SUM(IsSpecial) FROM [dbo].[FeaturesBase] where CaseCreatedTime < a.CaseCreatedTime AND ' + @featureName +' =  a.'+ @featureName+ ')  as EscalatedCount,  
        '''+@featureName+''' AS FeatureName,
        RequestNumber,
        ' + @featureName + ' AS FeatureValue 
    from [dbo].[FeaturesBase] a'

    exec(@sql);
End
```

I've tested  this and it should execute the following

```
SELECT INTO (Processed_CallingCountry) 
        (SELECT SUM(IsSpecial) FROM [dbo].[FeaturesBase] where CaseCreatedTime < a.CaseCreatedTime AND CallingCountry =  a.CallingCountry)  as EscalatedCount,  
        'CallingCountry' AS FeatureName,
        RequestNumber,
        CallingCountry AS FeatureValue 
    from [dbo].[FeaturesBase] a
```

You should be able to find more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: 9 months without writting and just beat me before I could finish my answer. Welcome back.

Comment: this looks like it could work; is there a way of validating the syntax of dynamic SQL?

Comment: To validate, you could simply validate by printing the sql variable print (@sql); in this case. If you need a more robust method this could be of use http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19132.how-to-check-the-syntax-of-dynamic-sql-before-execution.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going wrong here that need to be addressed before getting into specifics of how to insert the data:

1. Why is `featureName` an `NVARCHAR(MAX)`? Will it ever have more than 4000 characters in it? I suspect it should be closer to `NVARCHAR(20)`.
2. Why `featureName` allow `NULL`s? Shouldn't it be `NOT NULL`?
3. Most likely the `featureName` field shouldn't even be in these tables. You need a lookup table called `Feature` that has `FeatureID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` and `FeatureName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL`. These other tables then only have the `FeatureID INT` field and a Foreign Key defined that references `Feature(FeatureID)`.
4. You most likely don't need separate tables for the different features? They have the exact same structure, and you already have a field (i.e. featureName) to distinguish the rows. Why not just have a single `Processed` table that has fields for: `(FeatureID INT NOT NULL, escalatedCount int null, featureValue nvarchar(max) null, RequestNumber int null)`