# Dynamic tSQL Query from parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm struggling with a dynamic query in tSQL to be used with Excel ODBC.

SQL Server 2016 via ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

I found this article but it only uses the table name stored in a parameter, I'd need the actual table to be within parameter: [Simple dynamic TSQL query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108465/simple-dynamic-tsql-query-syntax)

```
declare @t table(value1 int, value2 nvarchar(1024))
insert @t SELECT 1 as value1, 'test' as value2
declare @where nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @where = ' WHERE value1 = 1'
set @query = 'Select * from @t'
set @sql = @query + @where
EXEC(@sql)
```

This results in the error message *Must declare the table variable "@t"*

Unfortunately I can't use temporary tables as the connector doesn't support temp tables.

My original query is far more complex and contains 6 different parameters all being injected at different points into the query and 2 table-parameters that hold temp results

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does it have to be a table? It looks like you want to use some variables and be able to use them in JOIN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare your table as part of your query. The table is declared and recognized in that scope:

```
declare @t table(value1 int, value2 nvarchar(1024))
insert @t select 1 as value1, 'test' as value2
declare @where nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @where = ' where value1 = 1'
set @query = 'declare @t table(value1 int, value2 nvarchar(1024)) 
              insert @t select 1 as value1, ''test'' as value2 
              select * from @t'
set @sql = @query + @where
exec(@sql)
```

Result:

[image]